# javers comparing lists in object giving inconsistent results

Tags: javers

I am struggling to see why the following doesn't give me the same results.

If I use Javers to just compare the two lists (which have items in different orders) then I get no differences as I have specified the AS_SET List comparison to ignore the order of items in the List.

If I then wrap those Lists as a property of an object the Javers returns that the elements of the List are different because or the order of the items in the List.

Should the AS_SET apply to Lists within Objects? It is as if it is being ignore

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<ListItem> list1 = ImmutableList.of(
                ListItem.builder()
                        .itemName("item1")
                        .itemValue("value")
                        .build(),
                ListItem.builder()
                        .itemName("item2")
                        .itemValue("value2")
                        .build()
        );

        List<ListItem> list2 = ImmutableList.of(
                ListItem.builder()
                        .itemName("item2")
                        .itemValue("value2")
                        .build(),
                ListItem.builder()
                        .itemName("item1")
                        .itemValue("value")
                        .build()
        );

        TopLevelClass tlc1 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(list1).build();
        TopLevelClass tlc2 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(list2).build();

        Diff diff = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET).build().compare(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(diff);

        Diff diffTlc = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET).build().compare(tlc1, tlc2);
        System.out.println(diffTlc);
    }
}
```

Classes below:

```java
package wibble;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ListItem {
    private String itemName;
    private String itemValue;
}
```

```java
package wibble;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TopLevelClass {
    List<ListItem> items;
}
```

Output when the above runs:

```
Diff:

Diff:
    * changes on wibble.TopLevelClass/ :
    - 'items/0.itemName' changed from 'item1' to 'item2'
    - 'items/0.itemValue' changed from 'value' to 'value2'
    - 'items/1.itemName' changed from 'item2' to 'item1'
    - 'items/1.itemValue' changed from 'value2' to 'value'
```

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways of doing it (lots of them)

**Method 1 - Update Code with @Id**

This similar to what `@kriegaex` suggested and is to add a `@Id` annotation to your code and update the class like below

```
public class ListItem {
  @Id
  private String itemName;
  private String itemValue;
}
```

**Method 2 - Entity Registration**

The `Method 1` has a downside that it needs code changes to your actual model and may not be always possible or desirable. In this case you need to manually register your entity

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<ListItem> list1 = ImmutableList.of(
            ListItem.builder()
                    .itemName("item1")
                    .itemValue("value")
                    .build(),
            ListItem.builder()
                    .itemName("item2")
                    .itemValue("value2")
                    .build()
    );

    List<ListItem> list2 = ImmutableList.of(
            ListItem.builder()
                    .itemName("item2")
                    .itemValue("value2change")
                    .build(),
            ListItem.builder()
                    .itemName("item1")
                    .itemValue("value")
                    .build(),
            ListItem.builder()
                    .itemName("item3")
                    .itemValue("value3")
                    .build()

    );

    TopLevelClass tlc1 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(list1).build();
    TopLevelClass tlc2 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(list2).build();

    Javers jvc = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET)
            .registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(ListItem.class, "itemName"))
            .build();
    Diff diffTlc = jvc.compare(tlc1, tlc2);
    System.out.println(diffTlc);
}
```

The output of above run is below

```
* changes on com.javerstest.ListItem/item2 :
  - 'itemValue' changed from 'value2' to 'value2change'
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04bf' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04fb' added
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@29f62baf' added
* new object: com.javerstest.ListItem/item3
```

And without the `.registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(ListItem.class, "itemName"))`, it is

```
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04bf' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04fb' added
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@29f62baf' added
  - 'items/0.itemName' changed from 'item1' to 'item2'
  - 'items/0.itemValue' changed from 'value' to 'value2change'
  - 'items/1.itemName' changed from 'item2' to 'item1'
  - 'items/1.itemValue' changed from 'value2' to 'value'
```

**Method 3 - Using @IgnoreDeclaredProperties**

So after clarification on later section, another way to do it is below

```
@IgnoreDeclaredProperties
public class ListItem {
    private String itemName;
    private String itemValue;
}
```

This will let the `List` compare work and rest items not added. But this will not let you compare a `ListItem` directly.

So the recommended way is to use `Method 2` only, if you don't want code changes to your models and also complete flexibility

**Method 4 - Using @ShallowReference**

One can add a `@ShallowReference` to the items and it will then do a proper Set comparison

```
public class TopLevelClass {

    @ShallowReference
    List<ListItem> items;
}
```

Currently as of **02-May-18** this doesn't work because of the bug explained later

**Method 5 - Using Sets**

You can use `Set` instead of `List` in your class if you want

```
public class TopLevelClass {
   Set<ListItem> items;
}
```

And the updated comparison code will be

```
TopLevelClass tlc1 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(new HashSet<ListItem>(list1)).build();
TopLevelClass tlc2 = TopLevelClass.builder().items(new HashSet<ListItem>(list2)).build();

Javers jvc = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
```

With the output as below

```
Diff:
* new object: com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/bd3fdf9ee4c8eb797ca392a1f8eb28c6
* new object: com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/ad5b96d68b6742a92d330f0d98bae8b3
* object removed: com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/a1961e7fd2e23b166e4d1b2acbe67263
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/a1961e7fd2e23b166e4d1b2acbe67263' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/bd3fdf9ee4c8eb797ca392a1f8eb28c6' added
    . 'com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/#items/ad5b96d68b6742a92d330f0d98bae8b3' added
```

**Method 6 - Register ListItem as value**

In this you can register `ListItem` as a value

```
Javers jvc = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET)
            .registerValue(ListItem.class)
            .build();
Diff diffTlc = jvc.compare(tlc1, tlc2);
System.out.println(diffTlc);
```

And the output is

```
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04bf' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04fb' added
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@29f62baf' added
```

**<s>Feature?/</s> BUG? <s>/limitation?</s>**

Now another thing that is happening here in the code is below, if you look at the output from our `Method2` without `.registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(ListItem.class, "itemName"))`

```
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04bf' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04fb' added
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@29f62baf' added
```

This is basically because of `ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET`, if you change it to `SIMPLE`, the output will change to below

```
  - 'items' collection changes :
    0. '...ListItem/item1' changed to '...ListItem/item2'
    1. '...ListItem/item2' changed to '...ListItem/item1'
    2. '...ListItem/item3' added
```

So in our original code

```
Javers jvc = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET).build();
Diff diffTlc = jvc.compare(tlc1, tlc2);
```

First it compares the `list` using `set` only and adds the change like below

```
* changes on com.javerstest.TopLevelClass/ :
  - 'items' collection changes :
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04bf' removed
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@306a04fb' added
    . 'com.javerstest.ListItem@29f62baf' added
```

But then it goes further again and does another diff on each item of the array as well, that is why an additional diff gets added

```
  - 'items/0.itemName' changed from 'item1' to 'item2'
  - 'items/0.itemValue' changed from 'value' to 'value2change'
  - 'items/1.itemName' changed from 'item2' to 'item1'
  - 'items/1.itemValue' changed from 'value2' to 'value'
```

So it is not that the `AS_SET` is not being picked, it is that the diff is first done for the `list` as `set` and at individual item level also. I have raise a issue about the same to understand it better

https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/669

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: Actually I never heard of JaVers before, I have just stumbled upon this question and became curious. So I am a complete greenhorn here.*

Looking at the [diff examples](https://javers.org/documentation/diff-examples/#compare-entities) in the JaVers manual, you read something like:

> **Configuration**
>
> JaVers needs to know that the `Employee` class is an `Entity` (...) It’s enough to annotate the name field with the `@Id` annotation (...)

So let's try this:

```java
package wibble;

import lombok.*;
import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class ListItem {
  @Id
  private String itemName;
  private String itemValue;
}
```

The console log becomes:

```
Diff:

Diff:
```

Answer (score 1):

As @kriegaex already mentioned, you can map `ListItem` as Entity or Value and it would solve the problem. But it would be the workaround, because `ListItem` looks like Value Object. Another workaround would be changing List to Set.

Looks like, for now you can't compare Value Objects in List wit AS_SET algorithm. There is an issue with generating ValueObjectIds in this case. The discussion is continued here https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/669